# How to smoothly animate objects in Android

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have a view object in Android and I would like to animate it such that it flows from right to left on the screen. I currently use `ObjectAnimator` with the following code:

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", (-1)* 50* currentTimeSlot);
animation.setDuration(90);
animation.start();
```

The counting variable `currentTimeSlot` is just incremented after 100 Milliseconds by using `handler.postDelayed`.

Actually the code works and does what it should. However, the animation is not really smooth and I would like to know how I can make the animation smooth? Do you have any idea?

**Update**: Here is the whole code with the Fragment and the custom view that should be smoothly animated:

```
public class Test extends Fragment {

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static final int DELAY_IN_MILLIS = 100;
    private int currentTimeLeft_MILLIS;
    int helpCounterRun =0;
    private boolean viewHasBeenCreated = false;
    private FragmentTestBinding binding;
    View view;
    Drawable dr;
    int currentTimeSlot;

    private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;

    public Test() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        currentTimeLeft_MILLIS = 90 * 1000;

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentTestBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        viewHasBeenCreated = true;
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        container.getContext();
        constraintLayout= binding.constraintLayout;
        view = new View(getActivity());

        dr = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.light_bulb_layer_list);
        currentTimeSlot =0;
        countDownTime();
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    private void updateScreen() {
        binding.textViewTimeLeftValue.setText("" + currentTimeLeft_MILLIS /1000);

        //Set the parameter and background of the view
        constraintLayout.removeView(view);
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0));
        view.setBackground(dr);

        //Shift view to the right at the beginning of the level
        if (currentTimeSlot ==0) {
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth());
        }

        // Shift the view 70 pixels to the left in each iteration
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", (-1)* 70* currentTimeSlot);
        animation.setDuration((long) (DELAY_IN_MILLIS*0.9));
        animation.start();


        // Set the ConstraintLayout programatically for the view
        view.setId(View.generateViewId());
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = binding.constraintLayout;
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintLayout.addView(view);
        constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
        constraintSet.constrainPercentHeight(view.getId(), 0.071f);
        float widthConstrainPercentage_element1 = 0.25f;
        constraintSet.constrainPercentWidth(view.getId(), widthConstrainPercentage_element1);
        constraintSet.connect(view.getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);
        constraintSet.connect(view.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
        constraintSet.connect(view.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
        constraintSet.connect(view.getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);

        constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(view.getId(),  1.0f);
        constraintSet.setVerticalBias(view.getId(), 0.049f);
        constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);

    }

    private void countDownTime(){
        currentTimeLeft_MILLIS = currentTimeLeft_MILLIS - DELAY_IN_MILLIS;
        currentTimeSlot++;

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                helpCounterRun++;
                if(viewHasBeenCreated) {
                    countDownTime();
                }
            }

        }, DELAY_IN_MILLIS);
        updateScreen();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        viewHasBeenCreated = false;
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }

}
```

**Reminder**: Does nobody have any idea how to animate objects in Android in a good way (such that the animation is smooth)? I'll appreciate every comment.

Comment: Why do you need the variable of `currentTimeSlot`? I think the last parameter is a varags, thus you can pass multiple floats. You may want to look at the documentation of that method though.

Comment: @Darkman: Thanks Darkman for your answer. I need the variable `currentTimeSlot` as this app is a actually a game. So this variable makes sure that the View object `view` is shifted from right to left during the game and as said before, it actually works. However, the shifting is not done in a smooth way. It just does not look good. This is why I am asking for another way to dynamically shift objects in Android that is hopefully smoother .

Comment: @Darkman: Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: A lot of unefficient stuff in your code. You should avoid using recursions (`countDownTime` in this case) for anything related to GUI. That `Set the ConstraintLayout programatically for the view` can be done once -- cache the variables (global). That last parameter of `ofFloat()` is a varags -- that means it will create an array of floats for each call. `ObjectAnimator` shouldn't be called frequently. Do you really need to `removeView()` and `addView()` each time? Does the `view` changed? -- This is quiet a heavy job actually. My [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68133647/10534012) ...

Comment: Here is another my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68073686/10534012) that might help.

Comment: @Darkman: Thanks a lot for your tips. I really appreciate it. I have to use a recursion and a runnable because this is supposed to be a game with multiple threads. I managed to call the animation just once. Regarding the `addView` and `removeView` I have to say that there should be multiple views at the same time and after some seconds the individual views will change meaning that the existing views will be replaced by new views (e.g. every 5 seconds). So I have to add and remove the views constantly. But I will try to think about how to make the code more efficient. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Darkman: Do you think I don't need to create a `new Runnable()` for every timeslot and call `handler.postDelayed`? As far as I see it I need some Threads and using `handler.postDelayed` is the easiest way to do this (but it might be inefficient as I don't know in detail how this method works). Do you think it is better to just create one Runnable instead of always creating a new one? And shall I not use any Threads within the GUI? But how else can I introduce a delay?

Comment: My suggestion would be that you create a background thread which call a handler just to update the view (Calling a handler incurs a bit of overhead/lag). Recursions can be replaced with a loop. Well, I'll write an answer based on my previous old answers. I am not sure if it will make everything smooth though and of course it will be just an example -- don't expect it to work by copy-pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as much as I could help. Without any images, it is hard to figure out a reliable answer for your problem. I've included some comments in the code. I could not test it either.

```java
public class Test extends Fragment implements Handler.Callback
{
    //Inner class. A background thread.
    private static final class CountdownThread implements Runnable
    {
        private final WeakReference<Handler> handler;
        private final Thread thread;
        private final long delay;
        private boolean isAlive;
        private boolean state;

        public final CountdownThread(final Handler handler, final long delayInMillis)
        {
            this.handler = new WeakReference<Handler>(handler);
            thread = new Thread(this);
            delay = delayInMillis;
            isAlive = true;
            thread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
            thread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public final void run()
        {
            //Unless suspend()/stop() is called, this will run forever.
            while(isAlive) {
                try {
                    synchronized(this) {
                        while(!state) this.wait();
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(delay); //Delay
                    final Handler hanRef = handler.get();
                    if(hanRef == null) {
                        isAlive = false;
                        handler.clear();
                        break;
                    }
                    final Message msg = Message.obtain();
                    //msg.what = 0;
                    hanRef.sendMessageAtTime(msg, SystemClock.uptimeMillis());
                } catch(final InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }

        public final synchronized void resume() 
        {
            if(isAlive && !state) {
                state = true;
                this.notify();
            }
        }

        public final void suspend()
        {
            state = false;
            thread.interrupt();
        }

        //After calling this method, the object cannot be reused.
        public final void stop()
        {
            isAlive = false; // In case interrupt() does nothing (Thread was not in sleep nor wait mode).
            thread.interrupt();
            handler.clear();
        }
    }
    //End of inner class



    //Global variables
    public static final long DELAY_IN_MILLIS = 100L;

    private FragmentTestBinding binding;
    private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    private Activity activity;
    private View view;
    private Drawable drawable; //Renamed from "dr".
    private Handler handler;
    private CountdownThread countDownThread;

    private long currentTimeLeft_MILLIS;
    private int helpCounterRun;
    private boolean viewHasBeenCreated = false;
    private long currentTimeSlot;

    @Override
    public final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        currentTimeLeft_MILLIS = 90L * 1000L; //90000L aka 90 seconds.
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), this);
        countDownThread = new CountdownThread(handler, DELAY_IN_MILLIS);
    }

    @Override
    public final View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        binding = FragmentTestBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        constraintLayout = binding.constraintLayout;

        activity = getActivity(); //This one can be cache locally. Avoid calling same method over and over again.
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.light_bulb_layer_list);

        viewHasBeenCreated = true;
        currentTimeSlot = 0L;

        updateScreen();
        countDownThread.resume(); //start/resume

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean handleMessage(Message message)
    {
        if(viewHasBeenCreated) {
            currentTimeLeft_MILLIS = currentTimeLeft_MILLIS - DELAY_IN_MILLIS;
            currentTimeSlot++;
            helpCounterRun++;
            updateScreen();

            //If "something", then suspend the timer and return "true".
            //After 90 seconds has passed. Once again, a guess work. 
            if(currentTimeLeft_MILLIS <= 0L) countDownThread.suspend();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public final void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopThread();
    }

    @Override
    public final void onDestroyView()
    {
        super.onDestroyView();
        stopThread();
    }

    private final void updateScreen()
    {
        //Now this is the hardest part. You did mentioned that the view will change
        //every e.g. 5 seconds. The existing view will be replaced by a new view.
        //But your code DOES NOT reflect that. You're only setting the "view" variable in "onCreateView()" once.
        //Futhermore, this method will be called every 100 ms and you're adding/removing the same view each time. 
        //I would NOT add/remove a view unnecessarily. This is somewhat heavy.
        //Instead, change the image/drawable/translate if I could. So the following code is just a guess work.
        //I am not sure if the "view" should animated first then a new view will be inflated
        //in the "constraintLayout" or vise versa?
        //Should this method be called infinitely? There should be a stopping point somewhere other than in onDestroy()/onDestroyView()!.
        //So make sure to call "countDownThread.suspend()" to pause the timer temporarily.
        //I would recommend you to rethink about the entire structure in this method.


        //Shift view to the right at the beginning of the level
        if(currentTimeSlot == 0L) {
            //constraintLayout.removeView(view); //Animating the view after removing it does not make any sense.

            view = new View(activity);
            final int viewID = View.generateViewId(); //cache
            view.setId(viewID); //Avoid calling "getId()" too often.
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0));
            view.setBackground(drawable);
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth());

            constraintLayout.addView(view);

            final ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
            constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
            constraintSet.constrainPercentHeight(viewID, 0.071f);
            constraintSet.constrainPercentWidth(viewID, 0.25F);
            constraintSet.connect(viewID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
            constraintSet.connect(viewID, ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID , ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
            constraintSet.connect(viewID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID , ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
            constraintSet.connect(viewID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID , ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
            constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(viewID,  1.0f);
            constraintSet.setVerticalBias(viewID, 0.049f);
            constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);

            binding.textViewTimeLeftValue.setText(String.valueOf((long) (currentTimeLeft_MILLIS / 1000D))); 

            return;
        }

        //Be careful with integers divison. Convert them or one of them to a floating point number then cast it back.
        binding.textViewTimeLeftValue.setText(String.valueOf((long) (currentTimeLeft_MILLIS / 1000D))); 

        // Shift the view 70 pixels to the left in each iteration
        //I do not recommend using numbers in pixels instead in dp so that every device will have a same animation.
        final ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", -70 * currentTimeSlot);
        animation.setDuration(DELAY_IN_MILLIS - 10L); //(long)(DELAY_IN_MILLIS * 0.9D)
        animation.start();
    }

    //Must be called or else the thread would not stop.
    private final void stopThread()
    {
        if(countDownThread != null) {
            viewHasBeenCreated = false;
            countDownThread.stop();
            countDownThread = null;
            handler = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is an example of CountDownTimer. You may want to play with the duration depending on your needs.

```java
public class Test extends Fragment
{
    private CountDownTimer cdt;
    private static final long DURATION = 40000L; //40sec
    private static final long DELAY = 100L; //100ms

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //...
        countDownTime();
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    private void countDownTime()
    {
        cdt = new CountDownTimer(DURATION, DELAY) {
            boolean delay = true;
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if(delay) { delay = false;
                } else {
                    updateScreen();
                    delay = true;
                }
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                updateScreen();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        viewHasBeenCreated = false;
        cdt.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. I had a look into your suggested code and I managed to adapt some parts of it in my code as I now only add a view and the constraints the first time it appears in the game. However, I still create a `new Runnable()`  every 100ms and use `handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() `. Why would you not use this approach? To be totally honest, I have great difficulties understanding your thread handling (as I am not experienced with this). So I found the `handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()` approach way easier.

Comment: @VanessaF Well, that is mostly because I do not want to use recursions. Recursions cause a lot of overhead. Using `handler.postDelayed()` is suppose to be used for something quick and not a for long / repeated task. It will run on a UI thread after all and you certainly do not want to put a stress on it. Using that can also causes a memory leak ('Runnable` thread in this case). It is all up to you by the way. Anyways, the `CountdownThread` can used as is I think. What it does is sleeping for 100ms (`Thread.sleep(delay); //Delay`) ==> calling handler ==> calling `handleMessage()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You wrote "It will run on a UI thread after all". Is there a way to not run it on a UI thread? Further I noticed that when using `handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {` I create a new Runnable every 100ms and thus a new thread. So after e.g. 20 seconds I will have 20*10 = 200 threads running. Is there a way not to create a new Runnable but still use the `handler.postDelayed()` code? Your suggested approach is quite complex for me and I don't want to just use something by coping & pasting it without understanding what is going on.

Comment: Again, `handler.postDelayed` will block the UI thread. That means it will only update the UI after the `Runnable` is done. This something that you can try it for yourself. I'd suggest you to look for `CountDownTimer` examples. It is very easy to use. In your case, you're probably want something like this: `new CountDownTimer(20000L /*20 sec*/, 100L /*100 ms elipsed*/) { ... }`. To add a delay, use a counter to skip the very first and reset for the second run. You are also might want to use a appropriate value for the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. So shall I use the `CountDownTimer` to make a recursion inside its `public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)` or `public void onFinish()` method? You said that it is not advisable to use a recursion. How can I do this without using your suggested approach (that is way too complex for me)? As far as I understand I have to use a recursion even when using CountDownTimer. I don't understand what you mean by "To add a delay, use a counter to skip the very first and reset for the second run"

Comment: As its name suggested, it will call `onTick` between intervals so no recursions is needed. However the [CountDownTimer doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer#java) says that `onTick` won't ever occur before the previous callback is complete, so you won't always got accurate intervals. I'll add an example in my answer later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it.  I implemented the `CountDownTimer` as you suggested but honestly I don't know why this should be better than the `handler.postDelayed` approach. I even have the impression that the animation is less smoove and that the GUI is not responding as fast as when using the `handler.postDelayed` approach. Further, when using the `CountDownTimer` approach you have to specify in the beginning how long it should run. As I can't know how much time the calculations of the single timeslots in my game need, this is not possible to specify.

Comment: Thanks Darkman for your answer. Any comments to my last comment regarding the benefits of your suggested approach compared to the `handler.postDelayed` approach?

Comment: @VanessaF Are you stil having this problem? My first approach let you run the timer forever. You can also set a long duration for `CountDownTimer` and when you decide to stop it, call `cancel()`. About `postDelayed()` -- This is something that you have to decide by yourself. Do some tests, if it works wonder, then use it. You can also minimise your problem a bit and make a new cleaner question. Others might have different thoughts about this. One thing for sure is that you're not the only one doing animations, so a look at some tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort. Actually the animation still does not look as smooth as I'd like it to be. But I understand that you may be running out of ideas. Due to the fact that it looks at least a littlbe bit better and your effort, I upvoted and accepted your answer (but I will try to look for another solution).